# Any limitations of wait and notify which was covered in Java 5

Tags: java, multithreading

A generic question -, was there any limitations of wait and notify those has been covered in Java 5 release.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: limitations w.r.t  what ?

Comment: This was question as it is asked to me in a interview , couldn't myself make much sense of it ,so thought of putting here for broader audience to get some ideas about it.

Comment: I guess the interviewer wanted to find out about what you know of the java 5 release - concurrent API was a big part of that release and I hope you did bring that up.

Comment: The most obvious limitation is that if you notify when no thread is wait()ing the signal is lost.  Java **5.0** provides stateful components so such signals are not lost. Note: In Java 5.0 at least the concurrency components were faster.  This is not so true for new version of Java.

Answer (score 2):

The locks that came with java 5 allow you for try if lock is available before acquiring; also caters to the fairness which wasn't easy in pre java 5 releases.
You should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) .

Also, java 5 brings in atomic classes which helps in writing waiting free algorithms using the hardware CAS support. You should read about the atomic class (example AtomicInteger)

Tha java 5 release has a rich API which mostly does away with any use of wait and notify in client code - replacing such use with the more powerful locks and conditions. Also, blocking queues, semaphore, latch, thread safe collections are all important introduction that one show know.
In particular if you look at the Condition class it provides a more powerful way of doing something that was previously achieved using wait/ notify. Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

I recommend reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) and the book  concurrency in practice by Brian Goetz if you are a java professional.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I understand - Wait and Notify more of inter thread communication working on a shared lock.
but new in Java 5  ReentrantLock feature to check if lock is available more on alternative to synchorinzed block. It doesn't cover about wait/notify

Comment: I would appreciate - if you could give more detail/link for this
"Tha java 5 release has a rich API which mostly does away with any use of wait and notify in client code - replacing such use with the more powerful locks and conditions"

Comment: @anil I would appreciate if you read the links specified in the answer and come up with any specific question? I am also updating answer with link to the condition class which looks like your immediate concern.